# Getting error MySQLNonTransientConnectionException while using batch update in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Following cod:

```
String url;
ConnectionURL cURL= new ConnectionURL();
url=cURL.getCloudConnection();
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url))
{
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    for(int i=9;i<updateCformValues.size()-1;i++){
         List<Object> row=updateCformValues.get(i);
         String JDECode =(String)row.get(0);

        String CValue =(String)row.get(3);
        String updatedata = "update CRdataTable set OutstandingCFormValue='"+CValue+"'  where JDECode ='"+JDECode+"' ";
        log("String"+i);
        statement.addBatch(updatedata);
     }

    statement.executeBatch();


      conn.commit(); 
}

}
    catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        out.print(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Throws an excpetion

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. And, please learn about using prepared statements. Your current code is fundamentally unsafe and vulnerable to SQL injection due to concatenation of string values into a query string instead of using parameters..